# Стоит ли просить пользователей создать новый вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Здравствуйте.

Не так редко натыкаюсь на вопросы, где дают исчерпывающий ответ, но в комментариях от автора вопроса появляется что-то типа "спасибо, но как мне теперь сделать...?" - короче говоря, обсуждение выходит за рамки заданной темы.

Вот несколько примеров:

1. [Произвольные цвета при выделении, если для страницы заданы свойства «background» и «color»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595750/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-background/595809#595809) - тут автор спрашивал, почему в браузерах цвет выделения текста отличается, на что получил исчерпывающий ответ. Затем в комментариях образовались новые проблемы с какой-то библиотекой рендеринга текста, намеков на использование которой в самом вопросе не было.
2. [Как отправить в wall.post большое сообщение? (VK Open API)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598725/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-wall-post-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-vk-open-api/598746#598746) - тут я по хардкору объяснил человеку, почему нельзя отправить много текста, используя Open API и JavaScript SDK (JS-библиотеки для работы с ВКонтакте API), и посоветовал перенести публикацию этих длинных сообщений на бэкэнд, где подобных ограничений нет. Дальше в комментариях последовали вопросы на тему того, как получить ключ доступа для работы с VK API с помощью сервера - это тоже совершенно другая тема, которая не освящалась в вопросе.

... и где-то был еще один пример, но не мой, который я не смог найти. Уверен, многие из вас попадали в аналогичные ситуации или замечали что-то подобное.

Какова политика Stack Overflow касательно подобных ситуаций? Этично ли отправлять пользователя создавать новый вопрос, если его комментарии или апдейты сильно далеки от того, о чем он спрашивал изначально?

Comment: Да, в подобных случаях рекомендуется создавать новый вопрос. В таких связанных вопросах и ответах можно разместить ссылки друг на друга.

Comment: Без зазрения совести направляю на создание нового вопроса. Ибо сайт тут такой. Если нужно, покажите ссылку на свой прошлый вопрос, ради уточнения контекста. Это даже где-то в правилах написано.

Comment: Встречается еще и другая проблема: когда ответы на поставленный вопрос пишутся в секции комментариев. Прямо вот как сейчас :)

Comment: @alexolut, так набейте **свой ответ**.

Comment: @avp мой комментарий не является ответом, в отличии от Вашего.

Comment: @alexolut, просто у нас разные взгляды на этот сайт и свое место на нем.

Comment: @alexolut ну так набейте **чужой** ответ. В данном случае, это допустимо. Где-то на Мете было обсуждение подобной ситуации.

Comment: @PavelMayorov "просто у нас разные взгляды на этот сайт и свое место на нем." (ц)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Да, это нормальная и рекомендуемая практика создавать топики руководствуясь принципом "одна проблема - один вопрос", это сильно облегчает поиск по сайту (как встроенный, так и поисковиков).

Очень многие пользователи сайта считают, что раз им ответили чуть ли не в режиме онлайн на их вопрос - то это в их представлении означает, что можно задавать сразу несколько вопросов в том же топике. Но нет.

Давайте уважать не только право конкретного спрашивающего на получение ответа -- но и право десятков людей, которые не один год спустя смогут найти этот же ответ. Для этого лучше всего разделять разные вопросы, чтобы у каждого был свой заголовок, это очень помогает при поиске.

Основной критерий для ответа на вопрос "стоит ли создавать новый топик?" - именно то, насколько далеко ушли от первоначального вопроса. По факту, ответы обычно пишут вполне состоявшиеся в ИТ-области специалисты, которые могут понять, насколько близко в том или ином конкретном случае находятся вопросы.

Часто наблюдал такое, когда спрашивающий чуть меняет условия "а если бы потребовалось вот так поменять задачу" - и ему тут же говорят, что вот если вот так чуть поменять условия -- то будет очень интересный, но совершенно иной вопрос и решать его нужно будет по-другому. И как раз тогда рекомендуют создать отдельный вопрос и добавить ссылки между вопросами.

Answer (score 8):

Если ответ на дополнительный вопрос занимает одну строку, то можно просто взять и ответить. Если же там нужно что-то крупное и самодостаточное, то имеет смысл просить запостить отдельный вопрос и дать на него ссылку.